# How to conjoin multiple conditional renders in ReactJS?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have multiple conditional renders on my page. I have a table that shoes "discount" variables that represent different kind of discounts on a web store.
Only one discount can be active at the time. How to achieve this when there are multiple types of discounts (more than two shown on code). Otherwise normal price is shown represent by `result.price` variable.

My conditions:

```
    let today = new Date()
    let month = today.getMonth() + 1;

    let seasonalDiscount = false;
    if (month === 2 || 6) {
      seasonalDiscount = true;
    }

    let amount_of_salesDiscount = false;
);
    if (this.state.data2.amount_of_sales >= 100) {
      amount_of_salesDiscount = true;
      console.log('amount_of_salesDiscount: ' + amount_of_salesDiscount );
    }
```

Rendered table:

```
            <tr>

              <td>{result.name}</td>

              {seasonalDiscount ? <td>{result.price * 0.9} </td> : <td>{result.price</td>}

              {seasonalDiscount ? <td>No discount</td> : <td>Season Discount (10%)</td>}

              {amount_of_salesDiscount ? <td> {result.price * 0.85} </td> : <td> {result.price}</td>}

              {amount_of_salesDiscount ? <td> Amount of sales discount (15%) </td> : <td> No discount</td>}

            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all of it in a function that returns the final html tags based on the met conditions. Then call the function inside the render function. Otherwise it can get too messy if you use a lot of ternaries in the render function.

Comment: Possible solution. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are some mistakes in your conditions code

```
let seasonalDiscount = false;
    if (month === 2 || 6) {
      seasonalDiscount = true;
    }
```

Can be written as:

```
  const seasonalDiscount = month === 2 || month === 6;
```

Writing `month === 2 || 6` is a common mistake. If `month` is `4` in this example. It would resolve as `4 === 2 || 6` which is `false || 6` which is `6`. You can try this manually in a console.

This is how you'll write it in your rendered table:

```
export const renderSeasonalDiscount = () => {
  if (seasonalDiscount) {
    return (
            <>
            <td>{ result.price * 0.9 } </td>
            <td>No discount</td>
            </>
    )
  } else {
    return (
            <>
            <td>{ result.price }</td>
                <td>Season Discount (10%)</td>
            </>
    )
  }
}

const renderAmountOfSalesDiscount = () => {
  if (amount_of_salesDiscount) {
    return (
            <>
            <td> { result.price * 0.85 } </td>
            <td> Amount of sales discount (15%) </td>
            </>
    )
  } else {
    return (
            <>
           <td> { result.price }</td>
           <td> No discount</td>
            </>
    )
  }
}
```

Then finally in your render code you can call both functions

```
{
  renderSeasonalDiscount()
  renderAmountOfSalesDiscount()
}
```